# pointers,deallocation and vector in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I want to know that should i explicitly deallocate the pointers which are erase from a vector by myvector.erase(); .

For example;

```
Class Sample1{
   public:
         removeSample2(Sample2 * a)
         {
             if(// if i find that a is in my sampleList1 vector with index i ){
                   // should i call here delete or something like that for a pointer ?
                   sampleList1.erase(sampleList1.begin()+i);
              }
         }

   private:
      vector<Int *> sampleList1;

            } 

Class Sample2{
     public:
           // not important areas
     private:
          Sample1 * example;
             }
```

Comment: Use smart pointers (if you actually *need* a vector of pointers) and it will delete itself for you.

Comment: So, in my case should i delete , aren't i?

Comment: @L-caesar: I think you missed the point; you should simply throw away this approach entirely. There's no good reason to store raw pointers in a vector.

Comment: @EdS.: That's not really correct.  David's answer explains it better.  There's no good reason to store raw *owning* pointers anywhere.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's true, and was what I meant.  Are you telling me that you're not all mind readers?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way we could possibly know, since we don't know what you're trying to do. But the basic answer is:

1. If the collection logically owns the things in it, you are doing it all wrong. Never use ordinary collections of ordinary pointers for this purpose. Things will go horribly wrong if you, for example, copy the collection. (Either use ordinary collections of smart pointers or collections specifically designed to hold pointers and manage the lifetimes of the objects in them.)
2. If the collection does not own the things in it, then do not `delete` pointers from the collection. That will cause other code that uses those pointers to access an object after it has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You shall delete the element by yourself. vector did not allocate that element and so it will not free it.